# ionic http request not fired

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, http, ionic-framework

i am using ionic v2 , the problem is when i send http request it is not shown on chrome

```
   export class Auth {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello Auth Provider');
  }

  login(){
    console.log('Hello');
    this.http.post('localhost:8100/api/User/getAll/' , '' , {});

  }

}
```

i fire login method , it console out 'Hello' but not fire the http

that means ionic not firing the http call , i have installed white list plugin ,  edit xml file and install chrome extension  but there is nothing of those  solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `map()` the response then use the `subscribe()` method because the angular Http use `Observables`. check this

```
this.http.post('localhost:8100/api/User/getAll/' , ''  {})
 .map(res => res.json())
 .subscribe(
    response => {
       console.log(response);
     },
    error => {console.log(error)
  });
```